# Why won't Azure Devops Pipelines Docker Build stamp my commit version into my dotnet core assembly correctly?

Tags: git, docker, .net-core, azure-devops-pipelines

I found [Scott Hanselman's tutorial](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/AddingAGitCommitHashAndAzureDevOpsBuildNumberAndBuildIDToAnASPNETWebsite.aspx) on adding git commit hashes to builds using dotnet. I have tried to adopt his approach in my own project which is being built into Docker images in Azure Devops Pipelines. Unfortunately the git hash never makes it into the assembly.

In my docker file I have:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1-buster-slim AS base

ARG SOURCE_REVISION_ID

WORKDIR /app
RUN sed -i 's/DEFAULT@SECLEVEL=2/DEFAULT@SECLEVEL=1/g' /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf
RUN sed -i 's/DEFAULT@SECLEVEL=2/DEFAULT@SECLEVEL=1/g' /usr/lib/ssl/openssl.cnf

EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1-buster AS build
WORKDIR /src

RUN dotnet restore "Project/Project.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/Project"
RUN dotnet build "Project.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build /p:SourceRevisionId=${SOURCE_REVISION_ID}

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "Project.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Project.dll"]
```

The call to `dotnet build "Project.csproj"` uses the `/p:SourceRevisionId=${SOURCE_REVISION_ID}` argument as described in Scott's post.

I have discrete steps in my pipeline for the Build and Push docker agents as I found elsewhere that `--build-arg`s are not passed to Docker in a combined BuildAndPush job. I can see that the pipeline is passing the correct `SOURCE_REVISION_ID` to the build job, e.g. `--build-arg SOURCE_REVISION_ID=7397bf9c2650e6cd9452f5c40c6e1738fbb32532`.

I suspect one of a few things is the cause but I'm unsure which:

1. I am using incorrect syntax to retrieve the value of the `SOURCE_REVISION_ID` argument in my call to `dotnet build`.
2. I have misunderstood the difference between `ARG` and `ENV` in Dockerfile and need to copy the value of my build argument to a variable for use later. If this is the case, I don't understand why.
3. Actually it's working fine, but my code isn't extracting the `AssemblyInformationalVersion` from the assembly correctly (despite my copy and pasting of code from Scott's post!)

Please, help stop me from going bald!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using a multi-stage Dockerfile and specified the `ARG` in the first stage but actually reference it in the second stage. An `ARG` is scoped to the stage that it's contained in.  You should move the `ARG` to the second stage, after `FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1-buster AS build`.

Comment: Thanks Matt. This has got the source revision into the right place in the Docker build, and I can see the output from the variable now with a "RUN echo" in my dockerfile. I hadn't appreciated that "FROM" started a new scope like that.

Unfortunately I still can't see it stamped on my assembly but I'm beginning to wonder if I've got a dodgy version of the dotnet SDK as I can't even get the a direct call to "dotnet build -c Debug -p:SourceRevisionId=123456" to show anything in the resulting assembly. It isn't even showing in dotPeek!